# How to get relative path for logging.ini and log file in python over multiple OS

Tags: python, linux, windows, logging, python-3.4

I have created one wrapper logger class which actually wraps the functionality of logging module. I have created it so that every class in my application using logging doesn't need to add `logging.config.fileConfig()` and `logging.getLogger()` at the top every-time.

My wrapper class looks like this -

```
class MyFileLogger():
    # The config file for logging formatter.
    logging.config.fileConfig('logging.ini', disable_existing_loggers=False)

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.logger=logging.getLogger(name)

    def log_debug(self, message):
        self.logger.debug(message)
```

`logging.ini` file -

```
[loggers]
keys=root

[handlers]
keys=fileHandler

[formatters]
keys=myFormatter

[logger_root]
level=NOTSET
handlers=fileHandler

[handler_fileHandler]
class=handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=myFormatter
args=('testlog.log','midnight',)

[formatter_myFormatter]
format=%(asctime)s |%(name)-12s |%(levelname)-8s |%(message)s
datefmt=
class=logging.Formatter
```

`MyFileLogger.py` and `logging.ini` file resides on the same path. My intention to create `testlog.log` is also in same path as `logging.ini` file.

Implementation of the `MyFileLogger.py` would be like -

`imp.py` -

```
fileLogger = MyFileLogger(__name__)
message = "hey!"
fileLogger.log_debug(message)
```

Now this `imp.py` doesn't reside on the same path as `MyFileLogger.py` and `logging.ini`. That's why when I run it, this gives me below error cause the python is running at `imp.py` path.

```
  File "C:\Python34\lib\logging\config.py", line 76, in fileConfig
    formatters = _create_formatters(cp)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\logging\config.py", line 109, in _create_formatters
    flist = cp["formatters"]["keys"]
  File "C:\Python34\lib\configparser.py", line 937, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'formatters'
```

I know if I just give an absolute path to `logging.ini` and `testlog.log` it will work. But I don't want to go there, since this application can be ran in Windows or in Linux. So there would be path problem.

Now even if I don't care about the Windows-Linux thing and only concentrate on the Linux. There is another problem. So if we assume the current directory structure as this ("ProjectDir/src" is added in `PYTHONPATH` and assuming there is `__init__.py` in every module folders)-

```
ProjectDir
├── src
│   └── sales
│       ├── common
│       │   ├── logger
│       │   │   ├── logging.ini
│       │   │   ├── MyFileLogger.py
│       │   │   └── testlog.log
│       │   └── implmnts
│       │       └── imp.py
│       └── unitTest
│           └── test_MyFileLogger.py
└── bar.txt
```

Let's assume:

`imp.py` -

```
fileLogger = MyFileLogger(__name__)
message = "From imp.py"
fileLogger.log_debug(message)
```

`test_MyFileLogger.py` -

```
fileLogger = MyFileLogger(__name__)
message = "from test_MyFileLogger.py"
fileLogger.log_debug(message)
```

Then if I run `imp.py` I need to change the `logging.config.fileConfig('logging.ini', disable_existing_loggers=False)` to `logging.config.fileConfig('../logger/logging.ini', disable_existing_loggers=False)`

After that it will run but when I try to run `test_MyFileLogger.py` I need to change again to `logging.config.fileConfig('../common/logger/logging.ini', disable_existing_loggers=False)`

So my code is dependent upon which file I am running which I want to get rid of. Is there any way I can dynamically get the path of `logging.ini` and `testlog.log` independent of which file(from other path) is invoking this? I don't want to hardcore the absolute path, since this needs to run in both Windows and Linux, any solution?

Comment: I don't see why you have the `logging.config.fileConfig` call in the class definition. It only runs when the class is created when the module is first imported. It's fine since you should only need to load the config file once. I also don't really see the point of this class just to wrap calling `logging.getLogger(name)`.

Comment: Also, your config is using a relative path for the log file. That depends on the working directory, which depends on how your application was started and in most cases isn't something you should change. You should use a well-defined path for the log file location. It should not be created in the application directory. The user may not and probably doesn't have write access there. The log file should be created in a platform-dependent location in the user's home/profile directory.

Comment: I forgot to mention that you should find "logging.ini" relative to `__file__` in the module where you call `fileConfig`, e.g. `logging_ini_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'logging.ini')`.

Comment: @eryksun the main intention to put the log file to a relative path and in the application directory, so it can be tested in both Windows and Linux. There won't be any path collision.  The workaround for `logging.ini` worked. Can you tell me any similar kind of solution for `testlog.log` file.